# package-install doesn't load the package's files

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
M-x package-install
projectile
```

Projectile got installed successfully in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/projectile-20150201.1134/*.el`
then added `(projectile-global-mode)` to `.emacs`, but on restarting emacs, it cries foul as,

```
Symbol's function definition is void: projectile-global-mode
```

I can add projectile installed folder to load-path, but why doesn't emacs load its melpa installed packages automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `projectile` didn't load at the time you call `(projectile-global-mode)`. I suspect that you missed `(package-initialize)` or `(projectile-global-mode)` comes before `(package-initialize)` in your `.emacs` file.

Perhaps you want to check your `.emacs` file to ensure the order.

```
(package-initialize)
...
(projectile-global-mode)
```